# ScrollView RTL in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

The following code is my `ScrollView` in a `react native` project:

```
  <ScrollView
    ref={(scrollView) => { this._scrollView = scrollView; }}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    directionalLockEnabled={true}
    bounces={false}
    scrollsToTop={false}
  >
```

Now it moves from left to right, How it could move from right to left in first loading?

Answer (score 15):

For `RTL` setting you should write your code like the below sample:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const RTLScrollView = () => {
  const scrollRef = useRef();
  const scrollToEnd = () => scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });

  return (
    <ScrollView
      horizontal
      ref={scrollRef}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      onContentSizeChange={scrollToEnd}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
    >
      ~~~
      ~~~
      ~~~
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
  }
});

export default RTLScrollView;
```

**Hint:** I don't use your other `ScrollView` settings like `bounces={false}`, If you want, put it in your code, my answer is just a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm currently working on scrollview RTL.
I confirm by adding

```
contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
```

It is working fine on both devices. It'll work on IOS even without flexGrow: 1 but it is required on android to add this line.

I hope question is well answered now.

Moreover take into notice that RTL issue for scrollView is already fixed. only this line to add is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is truly an annoying Bug in React Native , ScrollView+RTL=Silly Bug.

Though , there are multiple hacks you can adapt , I did this to overcome the bug :

1. I reversed the data array I am using.
2. Used : onContentSizeChange event handler to trigger the
   scrollToEnd({ animated: false }) function on ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

you can try [invertible-scroll-view](https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view) that supports horizontal and vertical scroll view

Answer (score 0):

As @SlashArash has mentioned you can use the [react-native-invertible-scroll-view](https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view).
Here's an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import InvertibleScrollView from 'react-native-invertible-scroll-view';

export default class Demo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.scrollView = null;
    }


    render() {
        let categories = ['one', 'two'];
        categories = categories.map((category, index) => {
            return (
                <Text>{category}</Text>
            )
        });

        return (
            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
            }}>
                <InvertibleScrollView inverted
                    ref={ref => { this.scrollView = ref }}
                    onContentSizeChange={() => {
                        this.scrollView.scrollTo({y: 0, animated: true});
                    }}
                    horizontal={true}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                >
                    {categories}
                </InvertibleScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to build an autocomplete with an RTL scrolling. This proved to be tricky because the scroll to end solution caused a lot of flickering. I found the best way to make anything RTL is using the transform style. If you use transform, it is important that you apply the transform to each item in the list as well. Otherwise, you will have mirrored text. This solution also works if you want to invert top/bottom, just change transform scaleY instead of x.

Here is my ScrollView:

```
const renderList = () => {
  return itemList.map(item => (
    <Item
      key={item.id}
      address={item}
      style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: -1 }] }}
    />
  ));
};

....
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContentContainer}
  horizontal
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
  ref={scrollView}
  style={styles.scrollView}
>
  {renderList()}
</ScrollView
```

Here is the corresponding ScrollView style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    marginRight: 10,
    transform: [{ scaleX: -1 }]
  },
  scrollViewContentContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  }
});
```